# How can I analyze TypeScript / TSLint for slow processing bottlenecks in my React project?

Tags: typescript, performance, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, tslint

I have a React project (created with Create-React-App using the TypeScript template) that contains about 300 files (approximately 24,000 lines of code). We have also added a small number of additional project dependencies, including Redux, React-Bootstrap, and AWS Amplify.

The type-checking and linting in VSCode (using the TSLint plugin) used to be very quick. But after a couple months of development, the responsiveness of linting and feedback in VSCode has become increasingly sluggish to the point that type-errors and other language services can take up to 30 seconds or more to show up correctly in the editor after making changes to a single file.

Now I would expect some sluggishness if I had a large project with several thousand files, but with only about 300 files, I don't understand why processing is so slow.

(I would expect that TSLint and/or TypeScript can cache partial-build artifacts (e.g. ASTs etc) from imported dependencies in node_modules and from project src files so that when a single file is modified, they would not need to perform a full re-build from scratch.)

What I would like to know is what are some steps I can take to profile (or debug or troubleshoot in some way) the processing of TypeScript and/or TSLint to find answers to some or all of the following questions:

- Are certain linting rules taking an extremely long time to run?
- Which project files and/or package dependencies are causing the biggest slowdowns?
- Are there specific TypeScript type definitions, interfaces, or other language constructs in my src files that might be causing some kind of bottleneck or increased processing complexity for TypeScript or TSLint?

I know that it might not be possible to answer some of the above questions at the individual file or even package level, but I'm hoping to at least find out whether there are any "debug-mode" capabilities built into TSLint or TypeScript that might help me determine what is slowing things down, or what other strategies developers have used successfully in the past to resolve similar issues.